# lit-html: concatenating strings to use html``

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

I am programming a web-component with lit-element and wonder, how I can render a string inside of a variable which still has intact @click listeners with the html "processor" instead of the pure string.

```
someFunction() {
    var someString=`<button @click="alert('hi')">blah</button>`;
    return html([someString]);
}
render() {
    return this.someFunction();
}
```

doesn't work, while

```
someFunction() {
    return html`<button @click="alert('hi')">blah</button>`
}
render() {
    return this.someFunction();
}
```

works.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you try `return html(someString)` instead?

Answer (score 3):

**That is not possible.** These are two tagged template literal and function call fundamentally different things:

#### Tagged template literal

```
html`<button @click="alert('hi')">blah</button>`
```

Calling `html` as a tagged template function will call `html` function with n-argument parameters. First will be an array of the constant part of the template and arguments from second onwards will be interpolated valued.

#### Ordinary function call

```
const someString = `<button @click="alert('hi')">blah</button>`;
html([someString]);
```

Calling `html` as a function `html([someString])` will call that function with array as its first argument.

Being a language feature, the browser needs to understand a tagged template from ordinary function. It happens at a lexical/syntactical level and thus a tagged function must and must be followed by backtick(`) character.

In summary, tagged function `html` cannot exist without backtick. You can read more here on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).